# Can we fetch HTTP return code of previous call?

Tags: puppeteer

I search doc and the web, but can't find how to get the HTTP code of a query.

Anyone knows ?

Example :

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
const debug = true;

var base_url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/';

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com');

    // how to get HTTP code of last call ?

    await browser.close();   

})();
```

There's [response.status()](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#responsestatus) but don't know how to just fetch last query and not all with

```
page.on('response', response => {
    console.log("response code: ", response.status());
});
```

Comment: Can you share some piece of code?

Comment: As I see in docs `page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com')` returns `Promise<Response>` so just pass to the promise `then` method the callback function which will revice Response. But using await before `page.goto` should resolve the returned object directly to `Response` object.

Comment: Thanks, explaned in my response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, get it, thanks @Take_Care:

[response.status()](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#responsestatus)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
const debug = true;

var base_url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/';

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    cons ret = await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com');

    console.log(ret.status());

    await browser.close();   

})();
```